# Use variable set in child function in Parent function

Tags: powershell, scope

Say I have a child function.

```
function hello {
$x= 1
$y = 2;    
}

function outerFunction {

hello

$z = $x + $y

}
```

Is it possible to somehow do this?

Comment: Yes, you just need a dot before the function call: `. hello`

Comment: Can also set the scope of the variables, but Santi's suggestion is the way I'd take as well.

Comment: @AbrahamZinala: Can you show how?

Comment: so, inside your function you would set the scope of the variables: `$script:x = 1`. Then when you call on `hello`, you would load `$x` into the *script* scope making it available to you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Dot sourcing operator `.`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_operators?view=powershell-7.2#dot-sourcing-operator-) to bring the variables defined in the scope of the `hello` function to the scope of `outerFunction` function:

```
function hello {
    $x = 1; $y = 2
}

function outerFunction {
    . hello
    $x + $y
}

outerFunction # => 3
```

You could also consider a different alternative depending on your use case, where the operator is not involved. For example:

```
function hello {
    1, 2
}

function outerFunction {
    $x, $y = hello
    $x + $y
}

outerFunction
```